# Postgresql join on jsonb

Tags: postgresql, join

I have tables.

Orders table:

```
id: integer
items: jsonb
```

Items table:

```
id: integer
title: string
price: integer
```

example order record

```
id: 1, 
items: {
   "1"=>{"qty"=>3},
   "3"=>{"qty"=>12}
    }
```

example items records

```
 id:1, title: "Tesla model S"
 id:2, title: "Tesla model W"
 id:3, title: "Tesla model D"
```

Please, help get result:

```
id:1, title: "Tesla model S", qty: 3
id:3, title: "Tesla model D", qty: 12
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I did.
That query works.

```
        SELECT
        json_data.key AS id, 
        json_data.value::jsonb->'qty' AS qty,
        items.title as title 
        FROM orders, jsonb_each_text(orders.items) AS json_data
        INNER JOIN items ON items.id = json_data.key::int
        WHERE orders.id=1
```